# How to review code generated by camlp4

Tags: ocaml, camlp4

I'm using a syntax extension and would like to know if it's possible to output the generated code in some way.

I would rather avoid putting debug traces in the extension since I'm not the developer and doesn't know anything to camlp4.

Comment: What insight will this give you?

Comment: I hope it'll help me debug a runtime error thrown by the generated code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to find the root cause of the runtime error, i.e. in the code that is doing the generating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using syntax extensions (camlp4, ppx, ...) you can show the generated output using the `-dsource` option of the compiler.